# Custom activation function in Tensorflow with trainable params

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, activation-function

I am trying to implement a custom version of the `PElu` activation function in tensorflow.  The custom thing about this activation is the knee of the relu is smoothed. I got the equation from [this paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2022/papers/Biswas_Smooth_Maximum_Unit_Smooth_Activation_Function_for_Deep_Networks_Using_CVPR_2022_paper.pdf).

Here is the code:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def SMU_LeakyPRElu(x, alpha=2.5,u=1.0):
    return ((1+alpha)*x)+((1-alpha)*x)*(tf.math.erf(u*(1-alpha)*x))

from keras.layers import Layer

class SMU_LeakyPRElu(Layer):

    def __init__(self, alpha=2.5, u=1.0, trainable=False, **kwargs):
        super(SMU_LeakyPRElu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.u = u
        self.trainable = trainable

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.alpha_factor = K.variable(self.alpha,
                                      dtype=K.floatx(),
                                      name='alpha_factor')
        self.u_factor = K.variable(self.u,
                                      dtype=K.floatx(),
                                      name='u_factor')
        if self.trainable:
            self._trainable_weights.append(self.alpha_factor)
            self._trainable_weights.append(self.u_factor)

        super(SMU_LeakyPRElu, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return SMU_LeakyPRElu(inputs, self.alpha_factor,self.u_factor)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'alpha': self.get_weights()[0] if self.trainable else self.alpha,
                  'u' : self.get_weights()[1] if self.trainable else self.u,
                  'trainable': self.trainable}
        base_config = super(SMU_LeakyPRElu, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

x = tf.random.normal((1,10,4))
print(x)
input_shape = (1,10,4)

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape[1:], name="input_layer")
layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(2, 1,padding = 'valid', input_shape=input_shape[:1])(input_layer)
layer_2 = SMU_LeakyPRElu(alpha=2.5,u=1.0,trainable=True)(layer_1)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, layer_2, name="model")

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), loss="categorical_crossentropy", run_eagerly=True)

print(model.summary())
result = model.predict(x)
print(result)
print(result.shape)
```

I implemented this code using a example from [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58884/how-to-create-custom-activation-functions-in-keras-tensorflow) at Data Science SE.

Error:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 1.0467066  -1.1833347   1.5384735   2.078511  ]
  [-1.6025988  -0.30846047  0.8019808   0.3113866 ]
  [ 0.58313304 -0.90643036 -0.3926888  -0.6210553 ]
  [ 0.16505387 -0.5930619   0.6983522  -0.12211661]
  [ 0.06077941 -0.11117186 -1.2540722  -0.32234746]
  [ 0.41838828  0.7090619   0.30999053  0.10459523]
  [ 0.35603598 -0.2695868  -0.17901018 -0.09100233]
  [ 1.2746769   0.8311447   0.02825974 -0.48021472]
  [-1.536545   -0.24765234 -0.36437735 -1.1891246 ]
  [ 0.7531206  -0.56109476 -0.65761757  0.19102335]]], shape=(1, 10, 4), dtype=float32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-c9d490dfd533> in <module>
      5 input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape[1:], name="input_layer")
      6 layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(2, 1,padding = 'valid', input_shape=input_shape[:1])(input_layer)
----> 7 layer_2 = SMU_LeakyPRElu(alpha=2.5,u=1.0,trainable=True)(layer_1)
      8 
      9 model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, layer_2, name="model")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py in type_spec_from_value(value)
    888         3, "Failed to convert %r to tensor: %s" % (type(value).__name__, e))
    889 
--> 890   raise TypeError(f"Could not build a TypeSpec for {value} of "
    891                   f"unsupported type {type(value)}.")
    892 

TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <__main__.SMU_LeakyPRElu object at 0x7fde698f7850> of unsupported type <class '__main__.SMU_LeakyPRElu'>.
```

I don't understand this error. How should I implement this function as custom activation function with trainable parameters `alpha` and `u`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have named your activation function and the custom layer you created the same thing. I refactored your code for you.

**Code**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from typing import Optional
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


class SMULeakyPReLU(Layer):
  """``SMULeakyPReLU``."""
  def __init__(self,
               alpha: float = 2.5,
               u: float = 1.,
               trainable: bool = False,
               **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.alpha = alpha
    self.u = u
    self.trainable = trainable

  def build(self, input_shape: tf.TensorShape):
    super().build(input_shape)  
    self.alpha_factor = tf.Variable(
      self.alpha,
      dtype=tf.float32,
      trainable=self.trainable,
      name="alpha_factor")
    self.u_factor = tf.Variable(
      self.u,
      dtype=tf.float32,
      name="u_factor")

  def call(self,
           inputs: tf.Tensor,
           mask: Optional[tf.Tensor] = None
           ) -> tf.Tensor:
    fst = (1. + self.alpha_factor) * inputs
    snd = (1. - self.alpha_factor) * inputs
    trd = tf.math.erf(self.u_factor * (1. - self.alpha_factor) * inputs)
    return fst * snd * trd
  
  def get_config(self):
    config = {
        "alpha": self.get_weights()[0] if self.trainable else self.alpha,
        "u": self.get_weights()[1] if self.trainable else self.u,
        "trainable": self.trainable
    }
    base_config = super().get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

**Test**

```py
# fake data
x = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 4))

# create network
input_layer = Input(shape=x.shape[1:], name="input_layer")
layer_1 = Conv1D(2, 1, padding="valid")(input_layer)
layer_2 = SMULeakyPReLU(alpha=2.5, u=1.0, trainable=True)(layer_1)

# create model
model = Model(input_layer, layer_2, name="model")

# compile model and summary
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=5e-4),
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    run_eagerly=True)
print(model.summary())

# forward pass
result = model.predict(x)
print(result)
print(result.shape)

# Model: "model"
# _________________________________________________________________
#  Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
# =================================================================
#  input_layer (InputLayer)    [(None, 10, 4)]           0         
#                                                                  
#  conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 10, 2)             10        
#                                                                  
#  smu_leaky_p_re_lu_1 (SMULea  (None, 10, 2)            2         
#  kyPReLU)                                                        
#                                                                  
# =================================================================
# Total params: 12
# Trainable params: 12
# Non-trainable params: 0
# _________________________________________________________________
# None
# 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step
# [[[-1.6503611e+01 -3.5051659e+01]
#   [ 4.0098205e-02  1.5923592e+00]
#   [-1.4898951e+00  7.5487376e-05]
#   [ 3.1900513e+01  2.8786476e+01]
#   [ 1.9207695e+01  3.6511238e+01]
#   [-6.8302655e-01 -4.7705490e-02]
#   [ 9.6008554e-03  7.5611029e+00]
#   [ 4.7136435e-01  2.5528276e+00]
#   [ 2.6859209e-01  3.3496175e+00]
#   [ 1.4372441e+01  3.4978668e+01]]]
# (1, 10, 2)
```

Comment: @0-90  Do you know how can i register this custom activation as  object with Keras?

Comment: @ABMusicBox I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: how can i use  this sctivation function as string alias inside layers eg:                      layer_1 = Conv1D(2, 1, padding="valid",activation ='SMULeakyPReLU' )(input_layer)

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object